# Send mail to multiple recipients with attachment ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, system.web.mail

I am building a simple e-mail application to send emails to a list of people with an attachment.

To be able to add an attachment (from what I have found out) I need to use System.Web.Mail.

Is there any limit to how many email addresses I can send to at once?

Comment: Most likely if you add as many addresses to one email as theoretically possible, you will run afoul of every spam filter in existence.

Comment: Just an FYI, System.Web.Mail has been deprecated and it is now recommended to use System.Net.Mail

Comment: I missed that I could use Attache with System.Net.Mail. So I changed to System.Net.Mail instead.
Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email Protocol should not inherently limit the number of emails sent.
Any limits you'll run into will most likely be imposed by your server or ISP.